# assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod Not working

Tags: c#, .net, iis, attributes, webactivator

Basically my code look slike below:

```
    [assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(OpusOneCorp.Presentation.Client.Mvc.EndUser.App_Start.StructuremapMvc), "Start")]

    namespace OpusOneCorp.Presentation.Client.Mvc.EndUser.App_Start {
        public static class StructuremapMvc {
            public static void Start() {
                var container = InversionOfControl.InitializeForUser();
                DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container));
                ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IThreadRunner>().Check();
            }
        }

}
```

Well, I am not author of this code but it is implemented to run everytime the project is started and it is using Web Activator attribute to do that. It is really acting is a weird way on my machine. If I put a break point on it then it does not hit the break point at all, which means it is not hitting this code before the application starts.

secondly, when I do iisreset, it hits it the very first time but does not hit it any time further..... At the same time, it hits it every time on my colleague's computer....It is very inconsistent behavior and it just started acting this was. I have had this code for couple of months and it never broke but it suddenly started doing this. Of course it means something else has changed it but if it has broken it then it should never hit the breakpoints rather than deciding to hit it every time I do iisreset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using IIS on your colleague's computer or the visual studio built in web server?

The vs web server will restart the applcation every time you run the website from vs hitting the break point on the app start but IIS will only start the application the first time it is called. That's why it doesn't hit the break point again until you do a iisreset.